# Wrap text into svg shape in css (Indesign Style)

Tags: html, css, svg, shapes

I'm trying to justify text into an svg shape. 
like this kind of text design : https://www.pinterest.fr/pin/390194755195836422/

So I get the svg shape coordinates ( 252.721,218.867 126.361,291.824 0,218.867 0,72.955 126.361,0 252.721,72.955 )

I've heard about the "shape-outside" property, but not so much about the "shape-inside"

So I'm trying to get some help on that, I'm taking any leads you could give me.

I'm also wondering if this would be working on all browsers?

thanks in advance.